# Using Office Outlook API with hard-code user name and password

Tags: authentication, oauth, outlook, authorization, office365

I'm trying to build a (C#) web app that allows clients to make appointments with me. 
I'd like the web app to be able to read and add entries to my outlook calendar.
Many users will use the web app, but the web app will only access one outlook calendar - mine.
All of the examples I have been able to get working have involved the web app user interactively authenticating - but my users will not know my password.
I would like to hard code my username/email address and password in the web app.

When trying to acquire a token I get an error:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException:
AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application.
Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
```

I am not an administrator of the tenant. Is there any way I can get this to work without administrator involvement?
Would using some kind of certificate rather than a user name and password as user credentials help?

My code (currently in a simple C# console application) is as follows:

```
UserCredential uc = new UserCredential(MyUsername, MyPassword);
var AuthContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/Common");

// this doesn't work unless an unexpired token already exists
ar = AuthContext.AcquireToken("https://outlook.office365.com/", MyClientId, uc);

// this does work, but requires the app user to know the password
ar = AuthContext.AcquireToken("https://outlook.office365.com/", MyClientId, new Uri(MyReturnURI));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable use the username and password to request the token directly, we need to consent to use the app.

We can use the **OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant flow** to grant the consent by user. Here is an sample use the ADAL authentication library(**3.13.1.846**) to acquire the delegate token:

```
 static string authority= "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
 public static string GetDeligateToken(string resource, string clientId,string redirectURL)
    {
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        AuthenticationResult authResult= authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId,new Uri(redirectURL), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)).Result;
        return authResult.AccessToken;
    }
```

After we consent the app, now we can use the code in your post to acquire the token.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If I use the code that you provided, then it sends me to a web page to sign-in (and if I provide my user name and password then it returns a token). But when is that code meant to execute and by who? The web app that I'm trying to implement will be used by other users who don't know my username and password. Am I meant to execute the code that you provided ahead of time, retrieve the token and hard code it as a string in my web app? I thought these tokens would expire after an hour or so?

Comment: After you run the code in the post, login in the page with the account that you want to use in your original post. Then you could see a consent page, and after you get the access token, then the issue in your original post should be fixed( you already **consented to use the application**) .

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. So this consent lasts forever?

Comment: Yes. Unless you revoke the consent record.  You can manage the consent [here](https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r/#/applications)

Comment: Can this be done without signing off via the login page?  Completely programmatically?